# OSX Local Server Setup

Tags: ruby-on-rails, macos, web-services

I recently setup a local server on my mac.  I have rails and ruby and rack installed and running.

But I'm unsure of how to direct incoming request or have a rails app take control.

How do I move past just having the index page show and have pages like `http://10.0.0.2/example/test.html` or whatever load???

Any resources is much appreciated, or even a couple keywords to start googling

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easiest is to install passenger and use passenger preference pane to configure it.

http://www.fngtps.com/passenger-preference-pane

Comment: That crashes the Preference Pane everytime. I'm on 10.6.  Idk. What does that even do? Why is that useful?